# Linq, Python or Sql, need advice for TSS WSS BSS calculation

Tags: python, c++, linq, qt, pandas

Hi i am making a staditical soft in c++ with QT.

I need to make many calculation over a table with the output of multivariate cluster analysis:
Var1,Var2,Var3,..VarN, k2,k3,k4...kn
where Var1 to n are the variables of study,
and k2 to kn the cluster clasification.

Table Example:
Var1,Var2,Var3,Var4,k2,k3,k4,k5,k6

3464.57,2992.33,2688.33,504.79,2,3,2,3,2

2895.32,3365.35,2824.35,504.86,1,2,3,2,6

2249.32,3300.19,2382.19,504.92,2,1,4,3,4

3417.81,3311.04,2426.04,504.97,1,2,2,5,2

3329.66,3497.14,2467.14,505.03,2,2,1,4,2

3087.85,3653.53,2296.53,505.09,2,1,2,3,4

The c++ storage will be defined like:
QList table;

```
Struct record
{
   QList<double>    vars;
   QList<int>   cluster;
 }
```

I need to calculate the total, the within group and the between group square sum.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-test

So by example to calculate WSS for Var1 and k2 need to:
in pseudo code: 
get the size of every group:
    count(*) group by(k2), 
calculate the mean of every group:
    sum(Var1) group by(k2), and then divide every one by the previous count.
compute the diference:
    pow((xgroup1-xmeangroup1),2)
and many other operations....

Which alternatives will have more easy and powerfull codification:

1)Create a MySQL table on the fly and make SQL operations.

2)Use LINQ, but i does not if QT have QTLinq class.

3)Try to make trough Python Equivalents of LINQ Methods, 
 (how is the interaction between QT and Python, I see that Qgis have many plugin writed in Python)

Also in my app need to many make other calculus.

I hope to be clear.
Greetings

Answer (score 1):

After some time I respond to my self, 
the solution was maked in Python with Pandas.

This link is very ussefull:
Iterating through groups on: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html
Also the book "Python for Data Analysis, West McKinney" pag 255

This video show how to make calculation:
ANOVA 2: Calculating SSW and SSB (total sum of squares within and between) | Khan Academy 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j9ZPMlVHJVs

[code]

```
def getDFrameFixed2D():    
    y = np.array([3,2,1,5,3,4,5,6,7])
    k = np.array([1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3])    
    clusters = pd.DataFrame([[a,b] for a,b in zip(y,k)],columns=['Var1','K2'])    
    # print (clusters.head()) print("shape(0):",clusters.shape[0])       
    return clusters

X2D=getDFrameFixed2D()
MainMean = X2D['Var1'].mean(0)
print("Main mean:",MainMean)

grouped = X2D['Var1'].groupby(X2D['K2'])

print("-----Iterating Over Groups-------------")
Wss=0
Bss=0
for name, group in grouped:
    #print(type(name))
    #print(type(group))
    print("Group key:",name)    
    groupmean = group.mean(0)    
    groupss = sum((group-groupmean)**2)
    print("  groupmean:",groupmean)
    print("  groupss:",groupss)
    Wss+= groupss    
    Bss+= ((groupmean - MainMean)**2)*len(group)    

print("----------------------------------")
print("Wss:",Wss)
print("Bss:",Bss)
print("T=B+W:",Bss+Wss)

Tss = np.sum((X-X.mean(0))**2)  
print("Tss:",Tss)
print("----------------------------------")
[/code]
```

I am sure that could be do with aggregates(lambdas func) or apply.
But i don´t figure how
(if somebody know, please post here)

Greetings

Comment: I uses this, and I think the BSS isn't calculated correctly.  It shouldn't be a single group mean, but rather the assigned labels/clusters measured deviance from their assigned centers, squared, summed.